# Webpack dev server livereload on angular 2 template files

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

https://github.com/Kaffesumpen/keoom-angular

Here is my git repo if anyone wanna take a look.

---

Hello everyone I am trying to get my webpack-dev-server to do a live reload when I update the html and css/sass template files in my Angular 2 app.
Currently It make a reload when I change any ts file or the index.html file in the project.
How do I tell Webpack dev server to also make a live reload on the template files? the template files I am talking about currently are the templateUrl and StyleUrls in the meta description of the component.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl : './src/app/header/header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./src/app/header/header.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
  watch: true,
  entry: "./src/main",
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: "app.bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
      test: /\.ts/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader!angular2-template'
      },
      {
      test: /\.html$/, loaders: ['html-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })

  ]
};
```

**Bash command I run to start the server**

```
 webpack-dev-server --inline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally i found the bug, you are using a vary old version of awesome-typescript-loader which was causing this trouble. It never compiled your

`templateUrl: "./header/header.template.html"`

**to**

```
 templateUrl: require("./header/header.template.html")
```

in order to `webpack` could react on changes and make an reload

change to

`"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.1.1"`

will resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me.
Even if I remove the --hot flag it still don't pick up changes in the template files ( .html ) I do get Automatic refresh but only on the .ts files and that I get even with --hot flag

Comment: If i remove --inline flag as well ( as that is iframe mode ) I get the same result.

Comment: try to change this line {test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ["ts-loader","angular2-template-loader"]}

Comment: Still no refresh on the .html file

Comment: that's weird. any error in console? have you updated your app to rc.5? do you have repo in git so i can look it if it's ok?

Comment: Yes i updated it to RC5 today, I dident test this before I made the update. It could be that now all the components go through the Ngmodule maybe and that brakes Webpack.
But as this is my first time setting Webpack up I would assume it is my fault and not the update. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120840/discussion-between-bjorn-hjorth-and-mrjsingh).

Comment: I think it's because of the ngModule witch is preventing. I compared with my app and could find any thing strange but only different was ngModule.

Comment: @BjörnHjorth i have updated my answer it was issue with the awesome-typescript-loader. update it to latest will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine 